# Redis: Using one mset operation with bunch of expire operations in pipeline or bunch of set operation with expiration in pipeline

Tags: redis

In terms of performace which is better?, 
A: set 500 keys with mset and then 500 expires in a pipeline
B: 500 set with expiration in a pipeline too.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

MSET is a atomic operation, use them when you want atomicity for those keys, else use SETEX in pipeline. For performance you have to test them.